# What does the abbreviation “Tm.” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, abbreviation

What does the abbreviation *Tm.* mean? I got this in an email today and can’t figure it out, or find it on the Internet. Relevant sentence:

> (...) sodass ich Dir noch keinen konkreten Tm. nennen kann

I’m guessing it’s something like *at the moment* (from the context), but I wanna be sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the context I would guess it means **"Termin"** (date, appointment) but it’s not a common abbreviation.

[Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/TM) lists a lot of other meanings but they don’t make sense here either, so if "Termin" makes sense I’d safely assume that this was meant here.

I don’t see any way this could mean "at the moment".

Comment: Yeah you're definitely right. My guess was with based on the previous part of the sentence which I didn't include. Thanks

Comment: Agree with the interpretation (and thus, the answer), tend to disagree with the original usage - I don't see *Termin* abbreviated with "Tm" commonly (or rather: ever).

Comment: Could it mean Trade mark?

Comment: @Beta Apart from that this wouldn't make much sense, that’s grammatically impossible as "Trademark" is feminin in German but "konkreten" is declined for a masculine word.

Comment: @idmean: Feminine? I'd say neuter (although of course this does not change your concern).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Trademark

Comment: @idmean: Interesting, never heard it used like that and rather extrapolated from "*das* Warenzeichen" or "*das* Markenzeichen".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Foreign words seldomly get their gender from a German word with the same meaning. More often they adopt the gender of a similar sounding word. That’s probably also here the case, "Trademark" ↔︎ "die Marke", but that’s just my guess.